# Codeigniter htaccess redirect url with param

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect following url...

https://mypage.com/form/?object=123456

...with htaccess to...

https://mypage.com/form/object/123456

I don't like to enable enable_query_strings in config.php. Is there a way with htaccess to handle this? Currently, I have only the "basic" htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Many thanks for your help.

Greets, Yab86

Comment: Why is the redirect URL formatted that way? It is hard to imagine why that format is needed. Might be helpful if you show the `form` controller.

Comment: Third-party webpages do still have the old ugly url and I have to temporary redirect it.

Comment: Third-party webpages means? Pages not on your site?

Comment: Other webpages have links to my page (https://mypage.com/form/?object=123456) and I have a new webpage now. So the old urls have to redirect to the mentioned url https://mypage.com/form/object/123456. 123456 is variable